# Max output of crypt() function

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, crypt, string-length

Back when I used MD5 I used to create a varchar(32) column in the datebase.
However, I started using crypt(), and as I understand the output length is variable.
So which length should I set to the varchar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum number of characters returned is 123 characters.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Answer (score 0):

> For those wondering, like I did, what the maximum length of the
>   returned hash can be for the purpose of storing it in a database, the
>   answer is:
>
> 123 characters.

This is the top User Contributed Note from the [PHP: crypt Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)